Implicit formula to get all n choose k combinations without repeating

<----- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination
Consider the $n$ choose $k$ combinations without repeating. 
Is there an implicit formula $
A_{n,k}(i,j), 
\text{where}~
 0<i\le\tbinom{n}{k},~ 
0<j\leq k
$, where $A_{n,k}(i,j)$ repeats the entries of the i-row and the j-column of the following matrix-list (see examples below); for example $A_{5,3}(i,j)$:
123
124
125
134
135
145
234
235
245
345

For example: 
$A_{5,3}(1,1)=1$, 
$A_{5,3}(2,3)=4$,...

It's not clear at all what you're asking. Specifically the definition of $A$ is unclear

Presumably your inequalities should be $0<i\le\tbinom{n}{k}$, $0<j\le k$. For $j=1$ you could write
$$
A_{n,k}(i,1) = \min_r\left{r\in[1,k]\mid i\le\sum_{u=1}^r\binom{n-u}{k-u}\right}.
$$
Is the the kind of thing you're looking for?

Thx for the comments. I hope it is clearer now. Phew, I need to check the formula, but maybe.

@WillOrrick OK, this is a true statement. I asked myself whether there is calculation-like way, but I am not sure whether this exists.

Did you look at Wikipedia's article Combinatorial number system?

@WillOrrick And there is the solution "hidden"? I will read it. ;)

I don't want to promise too much. The solution, if you can call it that, will still involve the kind of threshold analysis seen in my earlier comment, but perhaps involving less complicated expressions. Also I have to warn you that that solution is for a version of the problem where combinations are written differently, namely, with elements in decreasing rather than increasing order. That has the advantage that it produces a method that is independent of $n$. If you want a method that works for your original way of writing combinations, you will probably have to introduce $n$ somehow...

@WillOrrick Yes, I can work with that! The example at the end of the wikipedi-article  gives what I am looking for, so TYVM.
